# regular expression for at least one zero in between 1s in a string

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to solve this problem but facing difficulty in writing regular expression..

Given a string, your task is to find the number of patterns of form 1[0]1 where [0] represents any number of zeros (minimum requirement is one 0) there should not be any other character except 0 in the [0] sequence.

Constraints:

```
1<=T<=20
1<=Length of String<=2000
```

Example:
Input:

```
100001abc101
1001ab010abc01001
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

Comment: What does the output 2 mean?  Twice?

Comment: There are two test inputs separated by space ... answer is 2 for each test input

Comment: @anubhava in 100001abc101 there are two sub strings matching our requirement 100001  and 101. Hence, the answer is 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("10+1");
String s = "100001abc101";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int i = 0;
while(m.find()){
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i);
```